# Ajax call is giving error 500 while returning value as JSONArray.fromObject(data) in Spring boot

Tags: java, json, ajax, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to get some jsonArray values to my ajax response body. But its giving error 500 all the time. I can see the call is on the controller and also printed the values. But for some reason, it's not going into the ajax response body. If I'm returning the class then i can see ajax call is working fine however whenver I'm trying to get those value to jsonArray . I'm using **Spring Boot.**
I'm getting this type error.

> GET http://localhost:5000/report/id?=2 500

ajax call:

```
  $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "/report",
           data: {
             id: id
            },
           success: function (response) {
                console.log(response)

      },
   });
```

controller:

```
@RestController

 @Autowired
 ReportDAO reportDao;

 @GetMapping(value = "/report")
 public @ResponseBody JSONArray getReport(@RequestParam(value="id") Integer id) {
  JsonArray report = new JSONArray();
  try {
     report = JSONArray.fromObject(reportDao.getReportById(id));
 } catch(Ex e){

  }
  System.out.println(report); // this is returing the value but not in the main ajax resposne call
   return report;
}
```

And the data I'm getting one my controller is in this format:

```
[{
  "dataUrl: "va",
  "id": 1,
  "status": "active",
  "dataJson": "[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Jon"
   }]

}]
```

Comment: Your error is actually most likely due to Spring internally trying to use Jackson (JSON library) to translate the fields in JSONArray to a JSON object.  ... So make the return type on this controller method whatever the return type is for `reportDao.getReportById(id)` and Spring should automatically translate it to JSON for you

Comment: Alternatively (and less ideal) and you can return type `String` instead of `JSONArray` and return `report.toString()`

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are doing the ajax call wrong. Your controller is setup to expect the `id` as a request parameter and not as a body. This, in turn, means that the URL you should hit should look like:

`/report/{id}`

Instead of passing it as part of the request's body. This in turn causes the `500` error you see since Spring excepts the parameter to be present since `RequestParam#required` value is `true` by default.

Finally not, that while you can use `GET` with a request body, I would advise against it as it is not good practice.

Comment: i tried to do as well you said `/report?id="+id,` its still giving 500  error. And the ajax call didnt give any error if I return my class `"report"` but when I'm trying to get that value as JsonArray im getting error. Controller has priniting the value but ajax call is giving 500

Comment: You should include any kind of application logs and stacktraces in order to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like springboot is most likely trying to serialize the internal working fields in your JSONArray to JSON, which isn't what you want.

Spring internally uses Jackson (a JSON parser) to automatically translate between JSON and Java classes. So if you return your DAO type instead of a JsonArray, Spring will behind the scenes call Jackson with something like `new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(myDAOReturnType)`

So something like:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/report/{id}")
public @ResponseBody MyDAOType getReport(@PathVariable(value="id") Integer id) {
   MyDAOType report;
   try {
      report = reportDao.getReportById(id);
   } catch(Ex e){
        // handle error
   }
   return report;
}
```

Where MyDAOType is the type returned from `reportDao.getReportById(id);`

NOTE: I also switched to using a PathVariable in my example because that seems more suitable for your scenario.